# What does a clause without a head mean in prolog?

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog, prolog-directive-dynamic

In the beginning of a Prolog program I see:

```
:-dynamic(path/1).
```

It seems to be a clause that doesn't have a head. What does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When Prolog interpreter sees `:-` in front of a clause when loading the program, the clause gets executed right away, rather than becoming part of the program "database". The most common use of the `:-` is defining the starting predicate of your program at the end of your program file, so that loading the file with your program causes it to run.

Specifically, `dynamic/1` [informs the interpreter that the definition of the specified predicate may change at runtime](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=dynamic/1). This is something the interpeter needs to know *before* reading the rest of your program, so that it could make special arrangements for uses of the `path/1` predicate.

Answer (score 5):

In a Prolog text, a term with principal functor `(:-)/1` is a directive.

A `dynamic` directive has the following effect:

- A predicate `P/N` is defined, even if no clauses are given. By default, executing a goal for a predicate without any clauses causes an existence error.
- The predicate may be altered by `asserta/1`, `rectract/1` and the like. By default, a predicate is static and attempting to modify it causes a permission error.
- The clauses may be inspected with `clause/2`. By default, a predicate is private and inspection with `clause/2` causes a permission error. On some systems (like SWI), all user-defined predicates are public and thus can be inspected with `clause/2`. So this effect cannot be observed in SWI.

Many implementations treat directives that are unknown as regular goals and execute them. However, implementations differ a lot as to the precise point in time when these goals are executed. When reloading a file, they differ even more.

If you want to ensure that a goal gets executed *immediately after the Prolog text has been prepared for execution*, use the directive `initialization/1`.